# Positioning UIToolbar swift

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, toolbar

I am adding a UIToolbar to a UIPickerview programatically and I want the toolbar to be positioned directly above the picker view, which is centered in the view controller. I have used the following to center the toolbar, but the toolbar ends up on top of (in front of) my picker view:

```
                    self.toolBar.center = self.view.center
```

I also tried the following, but the toolbar ends up at the top of the view controller:

```
                    self.view.addSubview(self.toolBar)
```

How do I go about solving this positioning issue?

below is the code used to build the toolbar:

```
                    self.toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
                    self.toolBar.isTranslucent = true
                    self.toolBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
                    self.toolBar.sizeToFit()
                  //  self.toolBar.center = self.view.center
                   // self.view.addSubview(self.toolBar)


                    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.done, target: self, action: Selector("donePicker"))

                    self.toolBar.setItems([doneButton], animated: false)
                    self.toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `toolbar` as an `inputAccessoryView` of `UITextField` after setting `UIPickerView` as `inputView` for `textField` like below,

```
textField.inputView = pickerView
textField.inputAccessoryView = self.toolBar
```

Remove adding `toolBar` as a subview

```
self.view.addSubview(self.toolBar)
```

Comment: Hi Kamran, thanks for the response. I added toolbar as inputAccessoryView, but I get the following error message. I"m not sure what means: "Cannot assign to property: 'inputAccessoryView' is a get-only property"

Comment: @Whitney do you have `textField` with inputView as `UIPickerView`?

Comment: @Karman, no, I don't. It's just a stand alone UIPickerView, where the user gets to select some random image.